# C++ Macro define and undefine

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, header-files, preprocessor-directive

I want to use macros to quickly create inlined functions in headers, these functions are related to a base class which I am subclassing. I'll put the definitions inside the base class header but I do not want to pollute everything that include these headers with all macro definitions, so I would like to write something like this (which unfortunately doesn't work):

```
#define BEGIN_MACROS \
#define MACRO_1(...) ...\
#define MACRO_2(...) ...\
#define MACRO_3(...) ...

#define END_MACROS \
#undef MACRO_1\
#undef MACRO_2\
#undef MACRO_3
```

And then use it like:

```
BEGIN_MACROS
    MACRO_1(...)
    MACRO_2(...)
    MACRO_3(...)
END_MACROS
```

perhaps should I use something like this?

```
#include "definemacros.h"
    MACRO_1(...)
    MACRO_2(...)
    MACRO_3(...)
#include "undefmacros.h"
```

And put definitions and "undefinitions" in two separate headers...

Or is there a better approach overall to overcome this kind of problems?
Or do you suggest to avoid at all the use of macros and/or macros in headers?

Edited to include specific use case:

definition:

```
#define GET_SET_FIELD_VALUE_INT(camelcased, underscored)\
inline int rget ## camelcased () { return this->getFieldValue( #underscored ).toInt(); }\
inline void rset ## camelcased (int value) { this->setFieldValue( #underscored , value); }
```

use:

```
class PaymentRecord : public RecObj
{
public:
    GET_SET_FIELD_VALUE_INT(PriceIndex, price_index)
//produces this
    inline int rgetPriceIndex() { return this->getFieldValue("price_index").toInt(); }
    inline void rsetPriceIndex(int value) { this->setFieldValue("price_index", value); }

};
```

Comment: It's probably best to avoid macros here alltogether. But still show us the use case. You may [edit]  your question.

Comment: The first problem with your first approach is that the line-continuation backslash creates a *single* line, and the preprocessor statements are line-based. The second problem is that the preprocessor is single-pass, macro-definitions created by a macro won't be parsed and handled.

Comment: Such extensive use of macros is typically a design error. Do reconsider or elaborate on your use case.

Comment: In general, you can't use macros to create preprocessor directives. The preprocessor just isn't that smart. The best you can do is optionally include pre-written directives with `#ifdef` ... `#endif`.

Comment: Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can not stack up more defines into single line (at least to my knowledge... What I would try to do is encapsulate those into 2 separate files instead like this:

**file macro_beg.h:**

```cpp
#define MACRO_1(...) ...
#define MACRO_2(...) ...
#define MACRO_3(...) ...
```

**file macro_end.h:**

```cpp
#undef MACRO_1
#undef MACRO_2
#undef MACRO_3
```

It just like your second case but the macros are not in single line ...

```cpp
#include "macro_beg.h"
 MACRO_1(...);
 MACRO_2(...);
 MACRO_3(...);
#include "macro_end.h"
```

But as  **Some programmer dude** commented this might not work properly or at all depending on the compiler preprocessor and macro complexity or nesting with class/template code. For simple stuff however this should work.

Comment: "you can not have include inside a function" - that is simply not correct. You can perfectly well have an include inside a function - even inside a variable declaration - for example `void f() { std::vector v = { #include "data.file" }; }` as long as you put the `#include` on its own line.

Comment: @JesperJuhl +1 didn't know that (probably remembering the restriction from ancient times before C++ standard or maybe even from my Pascal times) ... have tried it looks like the OP's second approach is working on mine compiler just the begin macro file have to be without '\' just like mine. Have updated my answer to reflect this.